# can't input data to mysql with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, connection

Hi everybody i have a problem with data input from html form throu php to mysql the connection has been done i test it and its working but i cant figure out why data isn't imputed ive double checked the database and its as should be

**registration form**

```
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>UserName</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
    <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td>
            <input type="password" name="password">
        </td>
    <tr>
        <td>
            First Name
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="fname">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Last Name
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" value="" name="lname">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            E-Mail
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="email" name="mail">
        </td>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Done!!!">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**database conntection**

```
<?php
    $db_adress="localhost";
    $db_username="root";
    $db_password="******";
    $db_name="accounts";
    @mysql_connect("$db_adress","$db_username","$db_password") or die ("Could not connect the DATABASE for more infos go kill yourself");
    @mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("No Database");
?>
```

**data input code**

```
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $fname = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname = $_POST['lname'];
    $mail = $_POST['mail'];

    $insert=("INSERT INTO 'register'(Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, email) VALUES (""'.$username.'", "'.$password '", "'.$fname.'", "'.$lname.'" ,"'.$mail.'")");
    mysql_query($insert);
    echo "Done";
```

I am glad for any help!

Comment: Not certain if this is the cause but `$insert=("...")` doesn't need brackets around it, just the quotes.

Comment: `echo "INSERT INTO 'register'(Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, email) VALUES ("'.$username.'", "'.$password '", "'.$fname.'", "'.$lname.'" ,"'.$mail.'")"` and test the query in sql console

Comment: You are exposed to sql injection please use PDO or atleast use mysql_real_escape_string() to sanitize data.

Comment: ***For the record:*** You accepted the wrong answer, syntax-wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***For the record***, you accepted the wrong answer, *syntax-wise*.

Table and column names are not to be wrapped in quotes, but either use no quotes or use backticks.

```
$insert=("INSERT INTO register (Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, email)  
VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password "', '".$fname."', '".$lname."' ,'".$mail."')");
```

or:

```
$insert=("INSERT INTO `register` (Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, email) VALUES 
('".$username."', '".$password "', '".$fname."', '".$lname."' ,'".$mail."')");
```

---

I also recommend you sanitize your inputs:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$mail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mail']);
```

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future PHP releases.

Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions. (which I recommend you use and with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo))

- **http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php**

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

---

I also noticed that you are storing passwords in plain text. This is not recommended.

Use one of the following:

- [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)
- [`bcrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt)
- [`scrypt()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt)
- [**PBKDF2**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2)
- PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

I think your syntax of query is wrong. Try given below.

```
$insert=("INSERT INTO 'register'(Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, email) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password "', '".$fname."', '".$lname."' ,'".$mail."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you are concating. try this-

```
$insert=('INSERT INTO register(Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, email) VALUES ("'.$username.'", "'.$password '", "'.$fname.'", "'.$lname.'" ,"'.$mail.'")');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of Single quotes and double quotes.

Try below code.

```
$insert=("INSERT INTO 'register'(Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, email) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password "', '".$fname."', '".$lname."' ,'".$mail."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your insert query is not properly enclosed in quotes. Try this

```
$insert= "INSERT INTO 'register'(Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, email) VALUES ('".$username."', '".$password "', '".$fname."', '".$lname."' ,'".$mail."')";
```

Comment: How is this any different from _three_ other answers herer?